# Facebook Like Box showing one face only

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-likebox

I have a problem with the Like Box - its connecting well with the fan page, showing correct number of likes, but in the box showing only one face... I know its not an issue of users permissions, because the page has more than 300 likes, and some of its users faces are appearing in another like boxes.

Anybody has an idea what can be wrong?

Comment: there has been a few issues with social plugins this afternoon, it maybe related and need to be reported as bug.  Can you link a few of your pages with like boxes on them please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just figured it out - the problem disappeared when in the field 'Facebook Page URL' instead of 'facebook.com/MyPageName' i've put 'facebook.com/pages/MyPageName/PAGE_ID'